# Having trouble with Tikz and Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

So I am trying to insert a functioning tikz image into a beamer project and it keeps giving me an error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Examples}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1},minimum size=20pt,scale=.8,
every node/.style={transform shape}] % If you want to scale the picture insert ``scale=
(something), every node/.style={transform shape}'' Ex:[level/.style={sibling 
distance=60mm/#1},minimum size=20pt,scale=.8, every node/.style={transform shape}] would 
scale to 80% of original size
\node [circle,draw] (z){\textbf{$u$}}
  child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (a) {\textbf{$v$}}
    child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (c) {}}
    child {node [circle,draw] (d) {}
    }
  }
  child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (b) {\textbf{$w$}}
    child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (e) {}}
     child {node [circle,draw] (f) {}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
./SDN Presentation.tex:61: Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.61 \end{frame}
```

If I delete the /#1 at the beginning of the picture I get an image though not the one I am looking for.  Not sure how to fix this issue since the code works for the amsart document class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Nice first question! (Has code ;).)

Comment: You may use `####1` instead of `#1` to define the `level` style.

Answer (score 23):

You need to pass the `fragile` option to the `frame` environment to stop `beamer` trying to parse things it shouldn't.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,trees,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Examples}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1},minimum size=20pt,scale=.8,
every node/.style={transform shape}] % If you want to scale the picture insert ``scale= (something), every node/.style={transform shape}'' Ex:[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1},minimum size=20pt,scale=.8, every node/.style={transform shape}] would scale to 80% of original size
\node [circle,draw] (z){\textbf{$u$}}
  child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (a) {\textbf{$v$}}
    child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (c) {}}
    child {node [circle,draw] (d) {}
    }
  }
  child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (b) {\textbf{$w$}}
    child {node [circle,draw,fill=black,text=white] (e) {}}
     child {node [circle,draw] (f) {}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: fragile tree]

Comment: Bro, I was losing my mind trying to solve a related problem with tikz and beamer and this [fragile] command solved all the problems. Thanks!