# # and other characters in a url

Tags: hyperref, urls

How do I place the url:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugarit#/media/File:Ugarit_02.jpg

into a PDF:

```
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugarit#/media/File:Ugarit_02.jpg}{Loris Romito}
```

I end up with errors like this, which are not overly helpful:

```
618: Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Your code works for me so the problem is in something else that you are doing and we have to guess what that is. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is.

Comment: @Andrew The code should NOT compile in this case. It should produce the error the OP wants help with.

Comment: @cfr True...my standard comment for this says this but, with edits, it was too long to fix in the comment box so I deleted this clause...

Comment: Try `\#'  It's what I use in \href.

Comment: The documentation for href implies that all escaping is turned off within the url parameter, so I was unsure what should or shouldn't be escaped. I thought I tried that, i'll try it again.

Comment: @Jacob: When I try your code snippet as-is in a minimal example, I get no error and the URL is properly sourced when I click on the hyperlinked text. So, perhaps you need to provide more information for us to replicate the issue...

Comment: It's probably easier just to use bit.ly or similar service to redirect to the tricky url.

Comment: Almost same question as [Having trouble with Tikz and Beamer - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234719/having-trouble-with-tikz-and-beamer) except that this one *also* have catcode issue, and escaping the `#` happens to solve both.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using the `\href` in the argument of some other command. This will break as `\href` no longer can change the catcode of the `#`. The exact error message depends on the outer command, but will normally report an `Illegal parameter`. In such cases you can excape the `#`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

%works fine:
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugarit#/media/File:Ugarit_02.jpg}{Loris Romito}

%fails:
%\textbf{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugarit#/media/File:Ugarit_02.jpg}{Loris Romito}}

%workaround: escape the #:
\textbf{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugarit\#/media/File:Ugarit_02.jpg}{Loris Romito}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there somewhere I can find a list of these illegal parameters? I'm not sure how to handle this for dynamic URLs.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with "`url`" or "`breakurl`" package and the tag is `\url{...}`, all the special characters are allowed for web link. And these packages having support with "`hyperref`" package...

Comment: That does not solve the problem of the question: he already uses a command allowing special characters in urls as you can see in `hyperref`'s `\href` macro. But try this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\url{http://www.foo.de/#bla}}}
\end{document}` and you'll see that `\url` has the same problem when used inside another macro…